# downloading from database

Tags: php, download, database

I have a small problem with the php content-disposition, I kind of understand where the problem lies but I have no idea how to solve it (new to using databases). Calling this php page will result in not showing any of the echos and only showing the download box, which I intended for the "cv" only (not sure if it's working that way, because the downloadable file I receive cannot be opened)

Removing the `header(content...` line will result in showing the echos, but I won't be able to download the specified file. I want it to show as a link which would download its contents when clicked.

```
$newEmployeeName = $_POST['name'];
$newEmployeeArea = $_POST['area'];
$newEmployeeCV   = $_POST['cv'];

include('databaseConnection.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM participants");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $download_me = $row['cv'];
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$download_me");

  echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['area_of_exp'] . " " . $download_me;
  echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for asking here on [main]. I think this question is better off on [SO], given the coding and software used. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The `Content-Disposition` header will force the script to present anything echoed after it as a download. You would normally use this with reading a file from the file system, so you can offer that as a download. In your case, if you’re storing CVs on your server then you may offer them as a download as follows:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetchObject();

if ($row) {
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $row['filename']);
    readfile($uploads_dir . $row['filename']);
    exit;
}
else {
    die('Invalid CV requested.');
}
```

Obviously the above is a simplified version of the process and you will need to tweak it to fit your application, but that’s the gist of it.

Also, don’t use the `mysql_` functions. They’re deprecated (as per the warning on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)). Use either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or the new [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (MySQL improved) extension.

Comment: I modified the code before your reply and came across a simpler problem, could you take a look at it please... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418725/downloading-a-file-from-database