# Downloading data to a csv file from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, hyperlink, download

How do I specify the file to be downloaded from the database?

main.php:

```
    include('databaseConnection.php');

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM participants");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){


$download_me= $row['cv'];

echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['area_of_exp'] . " " ;

echo "<a href='download.php?file=$download_me'> cv </a>";

echo "<br />";
  }
```

download.php (which is where the problem lies):

```
$file = $_GET['row["cv"]'];  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
echo $file;
```

I want the CV to be downloaded when the link in main.php is clicked

Comment: If this is new code you should consider changing mysql to mysqli. The mysql library will be depreciated from version PHP 5.5 onwards.

Comment: Is the CV stored in the database or is it in a file outside of the database? In that case you could store a file location in your column CV.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415864/downloading-from-database

Comment: @YourCommonSense is this an exact duplicate?

Comment: @Mr.Radical the CV is stored inside the database

Comment: @YourCommonSense it's not a duplicate, i found a solution for a problem i had earlier and modified the code with a different question

Comment: @Joey939 with CV do you mean just text or an actual file?

Comment: @Mr.Radical no it is not, and I mean an actual file

Comment: If your `cv` column contains an actual file (i.e. `BLOB` type) you can just `echo` the value.

Comment: @Joey939 what is the extension from the file you like to download from the database? For example, txt, pdf, etc.

Comment: @jack I tried that. However, for some still unknown reason it did not work, so I switched to storing and downloading the files in the server instead

Comment: @Mr.Radical the extensions needed were docx and pdf. The following content-type worked for both:
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Comment: @Joey939 great to hear that you question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case your file is indeed in side your database you could retrieve it this way:

Main.php:

```
<?php
  $host = "hostname";
  $user = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $database = "database";

  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
  If (!$link){
      echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
  }
  else {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM participants";    
  $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){

echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['area_of_exp'] . " " . '<a href="download.php?file='.$row['id_participants']. '"\>'." cv </a><br />";
  }


}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

mysql & more specific version:

```
<?PHP
      include('databaseConnection.php');


      $query = "SELECT * FROM participants";    
      $result = mysql_query($query);

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)){

    echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['area_of_exp'] . " " . '<a href="download.php?file='.$row['id_participants']. '"\>'." cv </a><br />";
      }

      mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

download.php:

```
<?php


$id_participants = $_GET['file'];

$host = "hostname";
$user = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
If (!$link){
      echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
  }
  else {
$query = "SELECT * FROM participants WHERE id_participants = $id_participants";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
$size = $row['File_Size'];
$type = $row['File_Type'];
$name =$row['File_Name'];
$CV = $row['cv'];
// echo $size . "". $type . " ". $name;

header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
echo $CV;

}
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Mysql & more specific:

```
<?php

include('databaseConnection.php');

$id_participants = $_GET['file'];


$query = "SELECT * FROM participants WHERE id_participants = $id_participants";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
$size = $row['File_Size'];
$type = $row['File_Type'];
$name =$row['File_Name'];
$CV = $row['cv'];
// echo $size . "". $type . " ". $name;

header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
echo $CV;

}
mysql_close();

?>
```

The database layout:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `participants` (
  `id_participants` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `area_of_exp` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `cv` blob NOT NULL,
  `File_Size` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `File_Type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `File_Name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_participants`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91cb3/4

I advice you to not store the CV in your database.

Comment: @Joey939 make sure you add security measures to the code. Good luck.

Comment: I have solved it thanks to your code :D It finally works! thanks a bunch
I have followed your advice and uploaded the file to the server instead, and just used the id from the database to determine which file to download, minor modifications were needed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I expect there to be a filename in the `$row['cv']` variable?

Concerning files, you shouldn't echo the variable (that way you only display the filename).

To output files, you ought to use [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). Also, in your download.php-file, you try to retrieve a GET-variable that doesn't exist.

For example:

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. basename($file) . '"');
readfile($file);
```

You should be aware that the $file variable should contain the full path (be it absolute or relative) to your file. That's why I've used the [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)-function to get only the filename.

Comment: Thank you for your response and correction, how do I specify the file in ` $GET['file'] ` to be the file in the database?

Comment: Whenever someone visits the `download.php?file=cv/cv.docx` page, the file cv.docx in the cv-folder (starting from your current working directory) is downloaded to the client computer. Be careful using filenames as parameters: someone could easily hack into your system like that. I would advise you to use a cv_id or something similar from the db and fetch the filename from the db.
Also: I've not included code to check whether or not the file exists.

Comment: @Joey939 if the above answer works then your file is not inside your database. If that is the case that is much better then storing it in a database.