# Saved images in Heroku app are not being displayed?

Tags: php, image, postgresql, laravel, heroku

I am new to web development and I have just deployed my site using Heroku. I am using Laravel as the framework and Postgres as the database.

In my site, I have a feature of storing images in my public/images folder. If I saved the images and changed the file permissions before deploying it on Heroku then the images are being displayed. However, if the images are uploaded directly through Heroku, the images won't be displayed.

I am guessing this is caused by file permissions. Maybe because the images that are being uploaded in the public/images folder in Heroku is not inheriting the permission of the folder?

Comment: are the images being correctly uploaded to the desired directory?

Comment: Yes. I don't see it in bitbucket though but I think it's stored in heroku?

Comment: It's so weird because yesterday, after uploading the image it was displaying fine but today, I revisited the site and the image is not showing.

Answer (score 3):

The file system on Heroku is not persistent. You can't save files on the web server file system, and expect those files to be available for subsequent HTTP requests.

You need to use another persistence store, like storing those files on AWS S3 or in your database. There are also probably other addons that would allow you to save files simply enough.

Ref: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Here's an example of saving and displaying images from a Postgresql database: [Upload/Download file in POSTGRESQL database with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181667/upload-download-file-in-postgresql-database-with-php)

Comment: Can't I just save my images in bitbucket. I don't have a credit card to make an account on Amazon AWS

Comment: Bitbucket is where *you* can save things. Heroku can't save files in there. Your web server can save the files in your Postgres database.